# Starter for Delphi Network

Tags: delphi

I worked in Delphi 6 a few years.
Now I was beginning in Delphi network and I need some source code
For following things:
I want make chat application which to have two peer to peer clients
But I don’t know how I to measure time for two clients and show it on both 
Screens.
I also want to mark first client with 1,second with 2 ,,,,,
In some application I want to have value who accounting number of sending of both clients
Generally does it exist variable which is mutual for both clients?!
Can somebody to send me source code of this kind?!
Comments in source code will be welcome.

Answer (score 11):

For networking in Delphi, [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/) is just about all you need to know  :)

Tons of sample projects contained therein.

Comment: One of these examples is a mini chat ;-). But yes, despite the learning curve, indy is the way to go.

Comment: Despite the worse examples, I'd go with Indy10.

Comment: as long as you never want to update indy,