# Transfer files between a network computers

Tags: delphi

I want to write a program for transferring files and documents between a network computers. Many files may have been transferring at moment. every computer can receive and send files, it means system have to be ready to send files and listening to receive files.
I can configure program on each system as i want (for example give a list of connected computers' ip to program to choose target system for transfer file into)
Do i have to make Server-Client type applications or i can have JUST one program running on computers? I know question is vast but helping me to choose the best way will be appreciated.

> >
>   I want to write this program by Delphi 2010 and network computers os is Windows 7.

Comment: You've tagged this as "delphi", but don't say anything about "delphi" in your question ... is it even related? Also, as noted in David's comment below his answer ... this question needs to be a lot more specific in terms of language, platform, etc.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1260033/62576

Comment: can some one tell me why it got votes to close please? where is the problem? is it the best way i was looking for? i tried to make it clear but if somewhere is difficult to understand it simply can be asked!

Comment: This question is WAY too vast and unclear. I understand it as "Here's what I want, how do I do it?" which narrows down to "Someone do my work for me" Please, do as much research as you can by yourself and only come to StackOverflow with specific questions about specific issues, not for advise on how to do something.

Comment: i researched for a long time and i found many results (udp, indy,...), as i said in my question i could not recognize which way is the best and i know this is vast so i asked for help to choose the best way (not "Someone do my work for me"), so if asking from someone who have experiences to help choosing best solution is something wrong then this topic must be closed.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it peer-to-peer. The very same program can both listen for requests to transfer or receive files from other computers and issue its own requests to transfer or receive files to other computers.

Comment: can you send me a link of an example or article please?

Comment: @Armin: Not without a *much* more focused question. Punch "[peer-to-peer file transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer-to-peer_file_sharing)" into your favorite search engine. Think about such things as: How will my program instances find each other? Will every file be shared with every instance that requests it or will I used authentication? How will the user control what my program does?